# html label for attribute has no effect

Tags: html

I'm trying to improve this contact form:
[link removed]
i wanted to add correct labels, to set the input focus if you click the name.
Therefore i've added an id to the name field and the for="name" attribute to my label. In a clean page with only that label and input in it it works as expected.. but in that page it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a hint why that isn't working?

Edit: I know that the other labels and fields can't work.. i've just changed the first input to try things out ;)

```
<li><label for="name">Name</label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name"><input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40"></span></li>
```

Edit: the used form plugin seems to be messy and i'll try to switch to wordpress jetpack forms.. so question is solved

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to place focus on the inputs?

Comment: i've added the code.. but as already mentioned the syntax seems to be correct (it works in a blank page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check your code. Look at this:

```
<li><label for="Name">Strasse </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Strasse"><input type="text" name="Strasse" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40" /></span></li>
<li><label for="Name">PLZ </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap PLZ"><input type="text" name="PLZ" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40" /></span></li>
<li><label for="Name">Ort </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Ort"><input type="text" name="Ort" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40" /></span></li>
```

You're using for="Name" several times.

Comment: Moreoever, many of the `input` elements lack `id` attributes; they need such attributes, matching the `for` attributes. The match is case-sensitive; when using for="Name", the element matches one with id="Name" (not e.g. id="name").

Comment: sry.. i know that the others doen't work.. i've just changed the first one to try it out... the rest of the code is a total mess and I've just startet to clean it up ;)